# Get a random file in Fish shell

Tags: fish

I'm translating this Zsh function to Fish

```
function random_quote() {
  QUOTE_FILES=( $PREFS_ROOT/quotes/* )
  cat $QUOTE_FILES[$RANDOM%$#QUOTE_FILES+1]
}
```

Here's what I've got so far:

```
function random_quote
  set QUOTE_FILES $PREFS_ROOT/quotes/*
  cat $QUOTE_FILES[$RANDOM%$#QUOTE_FILES+1]
end
```

The `cat` line needs fixing still.  I know that `RANDOM` should be replaced by `random`, but I'm not sure how to do the rest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
function random_quote
  set -l QUOTE_FILES $PREFS_ROOT/quotes/*
  set -l n (math 'scale=0;'(random)'%'(count $QUOTE_FILES)'+1')
  cat $QUOTE_FILES[$n]
end
```

---

This answer is outdated. Please follow @Niklas's correct one.

Comment: Awesome.  Thanks!  Since I'm new to Fish some things that ought to be really easy are confusing, as I'm so used to thinking in terms of Bash/Zsh ways of doing things. (Plus it was late at night when I was trying to do this, and my brain was turning to pumpkin pie...)

Comment: This broke in Fish 3.0.2

Answer (score 5):

Just found out it's really simple, random itself supports getting a random entry from a list!

just use `cat (random choice $QUOTE_FILES)`

it also works without a variable `random choice /path/to/some/folder/*`

or with a bunch of arguments `random choice option1 option2 option3`

you can find the documentation for `random` here:
https://fishshell.com/docs/current/cmds/random.html